# Function was checked to return value A, but in main, the value was found to be -1

Tags: c, function

The bug seems to be in binarySearch function and the for-loop it is in. I have placed a few printf to check for values. binarySearch supposed to return value: 8, but index variable in for-loop is -1.

I apologise if the formatting looks terrible. Please give me guidance on how to to post nice looking code here.

Thank you so much!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int binarySearch(char[][7], char[], int, int);
void deleteAndMoveEntry(char[][7], int, int);

int main() {
  // all the variables
  const int MAXIMUM = 5000;
  char temp[7];
  char symbol[MAXIMUM][7];
  int sizeSymbol = 0, sizeDeleted = 0;
  char toDelete[MAXIMUM][7];
  int i = 0, j;
  int index;
  FILE *in = fopen("stockin.txt", "r");
  FILE *deleted = fopen("stockdel.txt", "r");
  FILE *out = fopen("stockout.txt", "w");
  FILE *errorFile = fopen("error.txt", "w");

  while (fscanf(in, "%s\n", temp) == 1 && i < MAXIMUM) {
    strcpy(symbol[i], temp);
    i++;
    sizeSymbol++;
  }

  i = 0;

  while (fscanf(deleted, "%s\n", temp) == 1 && i < MAXIMUM) {
    printf("Hi\n");
    strcpy(toDelete[i], temp);
    i++;
    sizeDeleted++;
  }
  // Should we sort array symbol? To implement later for fun

  for (i = 0; i < sizeDeleted; i++) {
    index = binarySearch(symbol, toDelete[i], 0, sizeSymbol);
    printf("%d\n", index);

    if (index != -1) {
      deleteAndMoveEntry(symbol, index, sizeSymbol);
      sizeSymbol--;
    } else if (index == -1)
      fprintf(errorFile, "%s\n", toDelete[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < sizeSymbol; i++)
    fprintf(out, "%s\n", symbol[i]);

  fclose(in);
  fclose(out);
  fclose(deleted);
  fclose(errorFile);
  return 0;
}

int binarySearch(char symbol[][7], char toFind[], int left, int right) {
  if (right >= left) {
    int mid = left + ((right - left) / 2);
    if (strcmp(toFind, symbol[mid]) == 0) {
      printf("%d\n", mid);
      return mid;
    }

    if (strcmp(toFind, symbol[mid]) < 0)
      binarySearch(symbol, toFind, left, mid - 1);

    if (strcmp(toFind, symbol[mid]) > 0)
      binarySearch(symbol, toFind, mid + 1, right);
  }
  return -1;
}

void deleteAndMoveEntry(char symbol[][7], int index, int size) {
  int i;
  for (i = index; i < size - 1; i++) {
    strcpy(symbol[i], symbol[i + 1]);
  }

  strcpy(symbol[i + 1], "");
}
```

Comment: Post example contents of input files like `stockin.txt, stockdel.txt`

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  IF not successful, then call `perror()` to display your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the function failed, to `stderr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by missing `return` statements in the recursive calls. Change the lines

```
  if (strcmp(toFind, symbol[mid]) < 0)
     binarySearch(symbol, toFind, left, mid - 1);

  if (strcmp(toFind, symbol[mid]) > 0)
     binarySearch(symbol, toFind, mid + 1, right);
```

to

```
  if (strcmp(toFind, symbol[mid]) < 0)
     return binarySearch(symbol, toFind, left, mid - 1);

  if (strcmp(toFind, symbol[mid]) > 0)
     return binarySearch(symbol, toFind, mid + 1, right);
```

Without those `return` statements, execution falls to the bottom of the function, where the return value is -1, which explains the behavior you observed in `main`.

Comment: a good start, but dues not catch all the problems in the OPs posted code

Comment: @user3629249, you have commented a bit about that. I encourage you to post an answer.

Comment: Thanks @RSahu. I corrected my code and it worked well now. What a folly I have made!

Answer (score 0):

regarding: *Please give me guidance on how to to post nice looking code here.*  One way to easily clean up the code formatting is to highlight/select all your code, then click the `{}` as that will (mostly) format your code.  Then follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

In C, the range of valid index values is from 0 through (number of elements in array -1)

Regarding:

```
for (i = index; i < size - 1; i++) { 
    strcpy(symbol[i], symbol[i + 1]);
```

this expression: `symbol[i+1]`, during the last loop, will be accessing beyond the end of the array.

regarding:

```
strcpy(symbol[i + 1], "");
```

the index `i` will be pointing past the last entry in the array when the preceding `for()` loop has exited.

So this: `symbol[i+1]` will be accessing 2 entries beyond the end of the array.

Both of these problems result in undefined behavior